# ¿Cómo convertir un string a numeros con punto de miles en jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estoy utilizando **Jasper Report** y de mi *Base de Datos* (**MySQL**) viene un campo llamado `cedula` que puede contener un `string` con punto de miles o sin ellos. Ejemplo:

```
3.456.678 o 3456678
```

Lo que necesito es convertir a un número de miles si no contiene la variable `cedula` dicho valor. Por ejemplo:

```
- Si viene cedula con valor 3.456.678 no quiero convertir.
- Si viene cedula con valor 3456678 quiero convertir.
```

Probé de muchas formas y no logro hacerlo si viene el valor `3456678`.

`$F{CIC_RUC}` es un *String* y utilizo un *pattern* como `#,##0`

Comment: Igual sería más fácil eliminar los puntos y hacer la conversión a numérico en la propia consulta sql para después en el jasper utilzar el patrón `#,##0` que indicas sobre una variable numérica.

Answer (score 1):

```
        java.text.NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            Number n1 = f.parse("123213");
            Number n2 = f.parse("123.213");
            System.out.println(f.format(n1));
            System.out.println(f.format(n2));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        run:
        123.213
        123.213
        BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Si necesitas decimales:

```
        java.text.NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        java.text.DecimalFormat df = (java.text.DecimalFormat)f;
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        try {
            Number n1 = df.parse("123213");
            Number n2 = df.parse("123.213");
            System.out.println(f.format(n1));
            System.out.println(f.format(n2));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        run:
        123.213,00
        123.213,00
        BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```